# GetThumbnailAsync for files picked with FileOpenPicker in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, storagefile, fileopenpicker

I'm trying to access all types of files with a FileOpenPicker and display the picked files in a list with thumbnails.

```
private void Pick()
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
}
```

This works and opens a view where I can either choose to pick files from "Photos", "One Drive" or "Phone". If I choose "Photos", it opens the familiar image picker where I can select pictures and then call

```
await storageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.ListView)
```

for the picked files without problems. If I choose "Phone", it opens a more advanced file explorer. When I choose a file from there (even if I choose one of the same images that work when using "Photos" picker), trying to retrieve the thumbnail throws an exception

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

What could be causing this and is there a potential fix?

Comment: Internally, the items  returned by **Photos** are backed by a database that has extra metadata, but the **Phone** ones are not (even if you pick the same file). That is the "why." Sadly I don't know the "how" other than to catch the exception. (I had thought maybe the `Path` or `FolderRelativeId` properties would have a clue, but they don't - you could try checking other properties to see if there's a clear difference).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to find an alternative strategy. Maybe copying the files temporarily to the local folder and retrieving them from there will work.